# php-libvirt installation on centos fails

Tags: php, libvirt

I am trying to install `php-libvirt` on `centos 6.4 64x` and there is an error in ./configure step:

```
checking for LIBVIRT... configure: error: Package requirements (libvirt >= 0.6.2) were not met:

No package 'libvirt' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBVIRT_CFLAGS
and LIBVIRT_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

The `libvirt` is already installed and the info is:

```
Name        : libvirt
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.0.3
Release     : 1.el6
Size        : 0.0  
Repo        : installed
From repo   : kernel-xen
Summary     : Library providing a simple virtualization API
URL         : http://libvirt.org/
License     : LGPLv2+
Description : Libvirt is a C toolkit to interact with the virtualization
            : capabilities of recent versions of Linux (and other OSes). The
            : main package includes the libvirtd server exporting the
            : virtualization support.
```

Where is the error ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably checking for the availability of the development files of the libvirt library. The stock version is shown below, since you are compiling your own, check if you have built it.

```
Name        : libvirt-devel
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 0.10.2
Release     : 18.el6_4.4
Size        : 862 k
Repo        : updates
Summary     : Libraries, includes, etc. to compile with the libvirt library
URL         : http://libvirt.org/
License     : LGPLv2+
Description : Includes and documentations for the C library providing an API to use
            : the virtualization capabilities of recent versions of Linux (and other OSes).
```